# Woher kommt der »Schirm« im »Bildschirm«?

Tags: etymology

Ich frage mich gerade, warum man, als man den Bildschirm erfunden hat, dieses Ding so genannt hat. Der Wortteil »Bild« liegt auf der Hand, aber warum »Schirm«?

Ein Schirm ist ein flacher und meist gewölbter Gegenstand, der von irgendeiner Vorrichtung aufgespannt wird, um jemanden oder etwas, der hinter oder unter dem Schirm steht, vor etwas zu schützen, das von der anderen Seite auf den oder das zu Schützende zukommt.

So schützt ein Regenschirm die Person unter dem Schirm vor Regen und ein Sonnenschirm vor Sonne. In der Science-Fiction-Literatur gibt es von diesem Prinzip abgeleitet auch Schutzschirme, die von einer speziellen Maschine erzeugt (also aufgespannt) werden. Diese Schirme umhüllen häufig das zu schützende Gut (Raumschiff, einzelne Person) rundum, um es vor Angriffen oder gefährlichen Strahlen zu schützen.

Dann gibt es noch den Lampenschirm, der wegen seiner Ähnlichkeit mit einem Regen- oder Sonnenschirm zu seinem Namen gekommen ist, und zumindest im Freien die Lampe vor Regen schützt. Die Schirmchen auf Eisbechern erfüllen keine Schutzfunktion, sondern werden aufgrund ihres Aussehens, und weil man sie aufspannen kann, so genannt.

Aber beim Bildschirm kann ich weder eine Schutzfunktion erkennen, noch eine Vorrichtung, mit der man einen Bildschirm im weitesten Sinn aufspannen würde.

Hätte ich dieses Ding erfunden, hätte ich es »Bildwand« oder »Projektionswand« genannt, vielleicht auch »Bildfläche«. Aber »Schirm« wäre mir kaum in den Sinn gekommen.

Kann mir bitte jemand erklären, woher der »Schirm« im »Bildschirm« kommt?

Comment: Möchtest du mit Elektronenstrahlen beschossen werden? :-)

Comment: Ich nehme an vom Lampenschirm. So wie eine Lampe mit punktförmiger Lichtquelle selbst nicht "hell ist", wenn der Schirm das Licht nicht streut, würde man den Elektronenstrahl ohne "Schirm" ja auch nicht sehen.

Comment: Natürlich mussten die ersten Bildröhren, um überall auf dem "Schirm" einen gleich scharfen Leuchtpunkt zu erzeugen,  Kalotten- also "Schirm-" förmig sein. Der Begriff "Schirm" für die Leuchtschicht taucht übrigens schon in den ersten Veröffentlichungen zur Braunschen Röhre von 1897 auf. Ferdinand Braun hat den Begriff also selbst und schon sehr früh erfunden. https://www.univie.ac.at/pluslucis/PlusLucis/972/braun.pdf

Comment: @chirlu: Werde ich ja. In jeder Sekunde meines Lebens, als Teil der natürlichen Höhenstrahlung, und als Folge natürlich vorkommender Beta-Strahler, die ich täglich esse, wie dem Kohlenstoff-Isotop mit der Massenzahl 14. Davon abgesehen ist der eigentliche Zweck eines Bildschirms nicht, mich vor Strahlung zu schützen. Immerhin erzeugten die Schirme, als sie noch mit Elektronen beschossen wurden, selbst gefährliche Strahlung (Röntgenstrahlung, durch das Abbremsen der Elektronen in der Leuchtschicht).

Comment: Der Lampenschirm schirmt das Auge vor den direkten, womöglich blendenden Strahlen der Lichtquelle ab und schützt sehr wohl. Auch der Bildschirm schirmt einen ab und fängt das Licht erst mal auf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Wort *Bildschirm* ist in seinem Ursprung zwar durchaus verknüpft mit dem Vergnügen an optischen Illusionen - aber es ist viel älter als das Fernsehen oder die Kathodenstrahlröhre, nämlich mindestens 150 bis 200 Jahre.

Bei Google Books ist ein Band namens ["Blätter für literarische Unterhaltung"](https://books.google.de/books?id=QiBRAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA147&dq=%22bildschirm%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJqcvVx7DPAhVlOMAKHftoDiwQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22bildschirm%22&f=false) archiviert, datiert auf das Jahr 1858, in dem es heißt

> Daß ihn feierlich umrauschende All ist der unsterbliche Barde, dem er ein kleines Liedchen ablauscht, dem er nachdichtend eine Grundidee abborgt, um sie auf dem Bildschirm des Zeitgeistes seinem Volke zu reflectiren.

Das Wort war offenbar damals schon populär genug, um es metaphorisch gebrauchen zu können. Ein [Aufsatz](http://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/books/9783486989298/9783486989298.162/9783486989298.162.xml) von [Ludwig Vogl-Bienek](https://www.uni-trier.de/index.php?id=35080) gibt eine Erklärung, warum das so gewesen ist. Er zeigt die Darstellung einer [Phantasmagorie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantasmagorie) (*) aus dem Jahr 1849 als [Rückprojektion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCckprojektion) einer [Laterna Magica](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laterna_magica) auf eine Leinwand ([hier ein Link auf das einzelne Bild](http://culturebox.francetvinfo.fr/sites/default/files/assets/images/2012/12/robertsonprojectionrecadre.jpg)) und schreibt dazu:

> Das gezeigte Arrangement der Rückprojektion verbindet die Funktion der Projektionsfläche als Schnittstelle zwischen Technik und Publikum mit der Abschirmung des Apparats gegen den Blick. Diese Verwendung führt in der optischen Branchenliteratur des ausgehenden 19. Jahrhunderts zu den Bezeichnungen: »Schirm«, »écran« oder »screen«, die der Etymologie des heutigen Bildschirmbegriffs zuzuordnen sind.

Der *Bildschirm* wurde also nach dieser Erklärung so benannt, weil er zum einen den Betrachter vor dem direkten Licht der Projektionslampe abschirmt, zugleich aber auch dem Publikum den desillusionierenden Blick auf die Projektionstechnik verwehrt. Der Fernseh-Bildschirm war dann später die Fortführung eines ähnlichen Prinzips zu einem ähnlichen Zweck mit anderen technischen Mitteln.

Zum englischen Pendant *screen* habe ich noch folgenden [Hinweis](https://nait5.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/elements-of-screenology/) zur Herkunft gefunden:

> It was during the early 19th century that the word “screen” began to attain meanings that anticipated its current uses within media culture as a means of displaying and transmitting images. The earliest such occurrence recorded in the Oxford English Dictionary comes from 1810 and reads: “To make Transparent Screens for the Exhibition of the Phantasmagoria”.

Das bestätigt also den Zusammenhang mit dem Aufkommen der Phantasmagorie-Vorführungen als frühe Vorläufer des Kinos.

Nebenbei - in Deiner Frage schreibst Du:

> Dann gibt es noch den Lampenschirm, der wegen seiner Ähnlichkeit mit
>   einem Regen- oder Sonnenschirm zu seinem Namen gekommen ist.

Es ist wohl eher so, dass er so heißt, weil er das direkte, blendende Licht der Lampe abschirmt und streut. Zumindest wurde diese Ansicht schon in [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=schirm) vertreten. Dort steht auch

> **γ)** *im hauswesen und bei gewerken schützende oder abhaltende dinge mancher art;* schirm, *eine zwischen rahmen auf füszen ausgespannte leinwand, die vor etwas gestellt wird, um dies dem anblick zu verbergen, auch* spanische wand.

Die oben erwähnte Projektionsfläche dürfte wie ein solcher *Schirm* gestaltet gewesen sein, das passt also zusammen. Und außerdem siehst Du hier die Verbindung zu dem Wort *Wand*, das Dir selber als mögliche Bezeichnung in den Sinn gekommen ist.

---

(*) Sehr viel ausführlicher ist der [englische WP-Artikel über Phantasmagorien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantasmagoria).

Comment: “Es ist wohl eher so, dass [der Lampenschirm] so heißt, weil er das direkte, blendende Licht der Lampe abschirmt” - was er freilich beispielsweise bei Deckenlampen, bei denen das Leuchtmittel unter einem Schirm weitgehend im Freien hängt, nicht tut. Aber möglicherweise ist das auch eher eine neuere Entwicklung im Lampendesign.

Answer (score 3):

Die Herkunft scheint sehr kniffelig zu sein, ein klarer Beleg fehlt wohl. M.E. hat die Verwendung 2 Gründe:

1. Aussehen: die Form der Braunschen Röhre erinnert einfach an einen Schirm.
2. Es wird etwas klar abgegrenzt, die Innenstrahlen werden am Schirm gestoppt und in Licht umgewandelt.

Ich glaube, daß es einfach ein schnell erdachtes Hilfswort war, das keine wirkliche sprachliche Entwicklung vor dieser Verwendung durch Braun hatte.

Answer (score 2):

Folgendes ist nur eine begründete Vermutung:

Der Duden gibt als Herkunft für *[Schirm](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schirm)* an:

> mittelhochdeutsch schirm, althochdeutsch scirm = Schutz, ursprünglich wohl = Fellüberzug des Schildes

Dies passt gut zu den Projektionsschirmen aus der Anfangszeit der bewegten Bilder, die ja nichts weiter waren als große, aufgespannte Tücher. Später wurde das Wort *Projektionsschirm* auch für solche Projektionsflächen verwendet, die kein aufgespannter Stoff waren, und schließlich durch das einfachere Wort *Bildschirm* abgelöst:

[image: Ngram »Bildschirm« vs »Projektionsschirm«]

Comment: Ein großes aufgespanntes Tuch war eine Wand aus Leinen und wurde daher nicht *Schirm*, sondern *Leinwand* genannt. Den Beleg, das *Schirm* etwas mit *Schutz* zu tun hat, habe ich (mit anderen Worten) schon in meiner Frage angesprochen, aber ich erkenne bei einem Bildschirm nicht mal ansatzweise eine Schutzfunktion. Dein Ngram ist ein starkes Indiz für den Übergang von *Projektions*schirm zu *Bild*schirm, erklärt aber nicht das Aufkommen von *Schirm*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Im Englischen ist der Projektionsschirm/Leinwand ein screen http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=screen, das würde den Schirm erklären. Auch wenn screen und Schirm beide mit Schutz zu tun haben, muss der screen nicht regenschirmartig aussehen. Paravents heißen auch screen, nur halt auf Deutsch nicht "Windschirm".

Comment: @cbeleites: Ich habe starke Zweifel daran, dass Wörter aus anderen Sprachen, die noch dazu keine direkte Verwandtschaft zum nachgefragten Wort haben, hier irgendwie weiterhelfen können.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: ist nur eine Idee, deshalb auch nur als Kommentar. Aber screen und Schirm haben viel miteinander zu tun lt. dem gelinkten Ethymologie-Lexikon kommt screen "from Proto-Germanic *skerm- (cognates: Old High German skirm, skerm "protection," [...]", usw. Für mich ist das direkte Verwandtschaft. Der Englische screen hat sich wohl entlang (ggf. Windschutz verwendet als)  Projektionsfläche für Bilder (1810) -> bewegte Bilder/Film -> Fernsehen -> Computermonitor entwickelt. An jeder dieser Stellen, besonders aber in den letzten 100 Jahren, in denen die entsprechende ...

Comment: Technologie maßgeblich in den USA groß geworden ist, ist es plausibel, dass der jeweils schon etablierte Englische Begriff "screen" in der neuen Bedeutung mit der (schon viel älteren) etablierten Übersetzung "Schirm" übersetzt wurde, als auch auf Deutsch die Notwendigkeit bestand ein Wort für die neue Technologie einzuführen. Das heißt nicht, dass ich sicher wüsste, dass es so war. Aber es ist ein möglicher Zusammenhang, der m.E. plausibel genug ist um nicht ohne nähere Belege/eine bessere Erklärung verworfen zu werden.

Comment: Und es gab Windschutz-Schirme (hierzulande: Paravent, Wikipedia sagt, mann kann es auch Wandschirm nennen, von frz. gegen Wind; Englisch wind *screen*), die als Schutz gegen Zugluft und Sicht verwendet wurden. Und deren Konstruktion (mit Stoff bespannter Rahmen) genau wie einfache (nicht falt-/rollbare) Projektionsflächen für Schattentheater, laterna magica usw. ist.

Comment: @cbleites Die Braunsche Röhre wurde in Deutschland erfunden. F. Braun , der den Begriff des Schirms geprägt hat, hat sich wohl kaum um englische Ethymologie gekümmert.

Comment: @cbeleites: Dass »screen« und »Schirm« etymologisch verwandt sind, war mir nicht bekannt. Ich bedanke mich für diese Information und ziehe jenen Teil meiner Argumentation, der auf der fälschlich angenommenen Nicht-Verwandtschaft beruht, zurück. Aber dennoch hat tofro recht: Der Bildschirm wurde nicht in einem englischsprachigen Land, sondern in Straßburg, das damals (1897) zum Deutschen Reich gehörte, von dem deutschen Physiker Ferdinand Braun erfunden. Die Sprache der Wissenschaft war damals Deutsch, um englische Begriffe hat sich damals niemand gekümmert.