# List of non-compound nouns by frequency

Tags: noun

I am looking for a list of non-compound nouns by frequency (e.g. *Haustür* would not be there, but its occurrences will be included in the count of *Tür*). [DeReWo](https://www.ids-mannheim.de/digspra/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo) does not provide this distinction as far as I understand. Does anyone know such a list?

Edit: my aim is to create an Anki-deck based on exceptions to gender and plural rules.

Comment: Is there any list of nouns by frequency?

Comment: The frequency will wildly vary with the considered text base and the benefit of such a list seems to include brute brute force password cracking schemes. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/d/worthaeufigkeit) has a rough classification, but whether *Bildschirm* is really to be considered a composite anymore?

Comment: Related: [Where can I find a parsable list of German words?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/491/43989)

Comment: @guidot: I do find the DWDS usage database and frequency rating very useful, but in my experience their text base relies heavily on newspaper articles. That means that words relating to politics, the stock market, war, crime, natural disasters, etc. get a higher frequency rating than they would with more a conversational base. Subtitles are more conversational, but then you start getting made up words like Minbari, used frequently but only in a certain movie or TV show.

Comment: @guidot: Why do you think a word can lose its character as composite word?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that such a list is able to exist. DeReWo has a list of basic forms of German words and it lists the frequency class for each word. (The frequency class of the most frequent word *»der«* is 0 per definition, and when word A is half as frequent as word B, then the frequency class of word B is the frequency class of word A plus 1.)

You can filter out all words with a capital first letter, and this gives you a list of all nouns (the most frequent noun is *»Zeit«* and it belongs to frequency class 5, the next is *»Uhr«* in class 6 then *»Prozent«, »Mann«, »Tag«, »Euro«, »Stadt«* etc. in class 7)

But you still have to solve a problem that is everything else than easy:

How can tell apart compound nouns from non-compound nouns? You can try to solve the problem on a very technical level: If the nouns can be split in two parts, you could call is a compound noun and leave it out from your list. (Maybe there also is an extra *[Fugenlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut)* between the two parts like the *e* in *Mauseloch* or the *s* in *Liebeslied,* but in some cases a *Fugenlaut* also can be a missing ending like the missing *e* in *Kronprinz = Kron**e** + Prinz.*)

But look at

> Mannschaft = team, crew, workmanship, personell

You can split it into

> Mann = man
> Schaft = shaft, stem, stock, leg

But here the suffix *-schaft* is the English *-ship* like *Freundschaft = friendship.*

or

> Sonntag = Sunday
> Sonne = sun
> Tag = day

In German and in English the word is built from the same parts (*"sun"* and *"day"*), but *Sunday* means something completely different than *"a sunny day"* or *"he day of the sun".*

> Bildschirm = screen
> Bild = picture
> Schirm = umbrella, shield

I am a native speaker who is very interested in German language and in the menaing of words, but I couldn't figure out how the *umbrella* came into the word *screen,* and so 5 years ago I asked here in German.stackexchange this question: [Woher kommt der »Schirm« im »Bildschirm«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/29815/1487) (Where does the "umbrella" in "screen" come from?)

> Jahrgang = age group, cohort
> Jahr = year
> Gang = corridor, hallway, gear, way of walking, criminal group, ...

The German word *»Gang«* is a multifunction word. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gang) lists 14 different meanings for the masculine version *"der Gang"* which is an inherited German word and 2 meanings for the feminine version *"die Gang"* which is a foreign word imported from English. But none of these 16 meanings can help you to understand the meaning of *"Jahrgang".*

And there are many other words which technically are made from two other parts, but will not be understood as a combination of two words. These words have a distinct meaning that is different form the meaning of their parts: *Bahnhof, Kindergarten, Zeitschrift, ...*